# How to spread div vertically to window size and center vertically?

Tags: html, css

So what im trying to do is to center text div vertically and spread it to window size so that is responsive for all sizes. This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2b1wm0pv/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="error-number">404</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

            <div class="error-small-title">ERROR 404!</div>
            <div class="error-big-title">Oooops, an error has occured!</div>
            <div class="error-description">We are sorry but the page you are looking for is not available anymore or you have entered the wrong address.</div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="error-button">
                    <a href="#" class="error-small-title">RETURN TO HOMEPAGE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why -1 ? i have fiddle i have code what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, explain clearly what is *your problem*. What text div?

Comment: i want to center text inside container...horizontaly and verticaly...and to have on bottom fotter and container to spread to full window size

Comment: display:flex or even table would sort this out easily ... but too much unusued CSS in your fiddle to take a closer look . you may use vh or wv units to set the font size of error-number and set a px size within mediaqueries for smaller screen

Answer (score 2):

To center the text, set the following CSS on the text div, or wrapping div:

```
.selector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

And the following on the parent element of that div:

```
.selector {
    position: relative;
}
```

Please note that the absolute positioned elements no long define the parent elements size, so it's highly recommended to define a width and height for this element.

To spread a div to it's page size u can use viewport (viewport = browser window) units: vw (width) and vh (height), where 100 is the size of the viewport, 50 will be half. This is different from using %, since % are relative to the size of the parent. So in your CSS:

```
.selector {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```